# How to declare a new partial function type in Scala

Tags: scala

The following is really for my understanding of the language.

How can I declare a new, specific partial function type. Let's say I'll need to declare many functions that are partially defined, take a MyClass class in and return a string. If I try:

```
class mypf extends PartialFunction[MyClass, String]
val myinstance: mypf = { case ... }
```

Scala complains that mypf should be abstract. How would I do that? Is it a bad idea to do it altogether? If so, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it doesn't solve your problem generally, it could help in that particular case:

```
scala> type mypf = PartialFunction[Int, String]
defined type alias mypf

// type alias for PartialFunction

scala> val x: mypf = {case x: Int if x > 10 => "More than ten"}
x: mypf = <function1>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had overlooked the "type" keyword That was the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If what you want is just to have an alias for PartialFuncion[MyClass, String], you should do

```
type MyPf = PartialFunction[MyClass, String]
```

this declaration is not possible at top level, it must be inside an object. If you want it to make it look very much like a top level declaration, then you can declare the type in a package object.

To go a little further, doing

```
abstract class mypf extends PartialFunction[MyClass, String]
```

is legal (it clearly must be abstract, it lacks an implementation for apply and is Defined). However, an expression such as `{case x => ...}` will be of type PartialFunction, not of your type, so your type will not be convenient.

Even without losing litterals, using inheritance just to get an alias is of limited use. If you do `class MyClass extends Something<With, Lots, Of, Parameters>`, `MyClass` will help when you create instances, but declaring method parameters of type `MyClass` prevents restricts the method unduly.

Answer (score 2):

A `PartialFunction` doesn't have to be defined for the whole input domain, hence the trait defines both `apply` and `isDefinedAt` as abstract.
Thus you have to implement the above methods like so:

```
val myInstance = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  override def apply(i: Int): String = {
    if (i < 100)
      "Valid " + i
    else
      "Undefined"
  }

  override def isDefinedAt(i: Int): Boolean = i < 100
}
```

You don't need to say `override` explicitly, but it is sometimes helpful to do so.